# React.js: handling events and function declaration vs function expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, callback

Am I missing something on Javascript functions ?:
**Does calling a function declaration creates an new Function object and executes this object, but calling a function expression execute the function Itself without "copying" It ?**

The reason for this question is below:

[Image source](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

[image]

> **The problem with this syntax is that a different callback is created each time the LoggingButton renders.**

Does this phrase means that:

1- a new function `handleClick` is created and called ? 
Or
2- a new arrow function is created at each render which calls `handleClick()`?

If 1, then whats the difference between the picture above and and using `onClick={this.handleClick}` (with binding `this`)? This will also call the method `handleClick`

Comment: Your second interpretation is correct. It creates a new arrow function each call to render.

Comment: @NickParsons Thank you. Regarding the first question: (Does calling a function declaration creates an new ...) is this interpretation correct ?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question entirely, but if you create a function declaration: `function foo() {...}`, and then call it later on `foo()`, in this case, `foo` is a reference to your function object in memory, so using `foo` won't "recreate" the object each time and execute it, but rather, will grab it from memory and execute it. Whereas, with a function expression such as the one you're passing to onClick, this function expression will be created each time your render function runs, so it will add multiple function objects to memory.